Weird sounding breakup poem
I happened upon this screenshot of the aftermath of a rough breakup.

Where are our two chatters from? And where are they now?
Poem from the image:

Goodbye psycho
I soothe, howl and sit
He is rotten
Damn, more hinge


Clue: There are 5 pieces of information. Names, first message, poem, phone country codes, phonenumbers.
I'd classify the following pieces of information as 'hints':

First message - Hint on how to solve poem
Names - 'Hint'/(checksum) on poem's solution
Country codes - 'Hint'/(checksum) on the solution after using the
phonenumbers with the result from the poem

None of this information are strictly necessary to solve the poem and then combine with phonenumber.

Post problem comment: (no non-text stuff in the screenshot is relevant, blurred text not relevant)

Is this about the sounds of the words?

Correct. 'barely/shitty homophones' could be a clue

are they now in rot13(terrpr naq cbeghtny)? I have no clue where to start solving the rest but rot13(gur pbhagel pbqrf) give that away.

Those are correct observations. But not the final answer. I will edit in a clue ().
